# Run Python scour SVG optimizer from script in stead of the CLI

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, svg, command-line-interface

[scour](https://github.com/scour-project/scour) for Python does a great job to reduce the size of the SVG maps that I have generated using matplotlib.

However, the documentation only describes how to run it for a single file from the CLI, standard:

```
scour -i input.svg -o output.svg
```

What is the best way to run it (in batch mode) from a Python script / from my Jupyter notebook?

I succeeded to 'create' the working code below and optimized 500 SVGs to my satisfaction. But I just copied that code in bits from the [testscour.py](https://github.com/scour-project/scour/blob/master/testscour.py) and I lack the understanding about it...

```
    from scour.scour import makeWellFormed, parse_args, scourString, scourXmlFile, start, run
    maps= os.listdir('C:\\Hugo\\Sites\\maps\\')
    for m in maps[:]:
        if afbeelding[-4:]=='.svg':
            inputfile = open('C:\\Hugo\\Sites\\maps\\' + m, 'rb')
            outputfile = open('C:\\Hugo\\Sites\\allecijfers\\static\\images\\maps\\' + m, 'wb')
            start(options, inputfile, outputfile)
```

Related questions (trying to learn): What is the best way to decompose a module like scour in order to find the right callable functions? (I would not have found the function start in scour.py ) Or could I have called the CLI command from the Python script above in order to execute it in batch mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your question because it pointed me to testscour.py, thanks a lot.

That said, the code imports scour first,
then makes makes a list from your map folder;
then goes through the list one by one, if it is an svg, it uses the "start" method to call scour.

so the working piece is 
`start(options, inputfile, outputfile)`

Note that it needs an opened file handler, usually you make that with "with".

Have fun

Comment: Thanks for your response! In the meanwhile I got a bit more experienced and realised that I should run my larger batch scripts directly from CMD rather than from within notebooks :)

Answer (score 1):

To use Scour programmatically first install it using PIP.

`pip install scour`

Then add this to your code (using whatever names you like).

```
from scour.scour import start as scour, parse_args as scour_args, getInOut as scour_io

def scour_svg(infilename,outfilename):
    options = scour_args()
    options.infilename = infilename
    options.outfilename = outfilename
    // Set options here or accept defaults.
    (input, output) = scour_io(options)
    scour(options, input, output)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    infilename = 'C:\\Users\\...\\svg_in.svg'
    outfilename = 'C:\\Users\\...\\svg_scoured.svg'
    scour_svg(infilename,outfilename)
    print('The END')
```

Use the `scour_svg` function to read in an SVG file, scour it, then write it out to a file.

Options can be adjusted in the code in the same way the `infilename` and `outfilename` are provided above. Refer to: -

- https://github.com/scour-project/scour/wiki/Documentation
- or just do `>scour --help` in the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Im using Python 3.11 and after looking at the answers already given here, I came up with this working solution:

```
# pip install scour

import os
from scour.scour import start, getInOut, parse_args


def scour_svg(inputfile, outputfile):
    options = parse_args()
    options.infilename = inputfile
    options.outfilename = outputfile
    (inputfile, outputfile) = getInOut(options)
    start(options, inputfile, outputfile)


def compress_svg_files_in_folder(folder_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith(".svg"):
            input_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            output_file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, f"compressed_{filename}")
            scour_svg(input_file_path, output_file_path)


def main():
    folder_path = "path/to/your/folder"
    compress_svg_files_in_folder(folder_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this context, I have to criticize Mark Kortink for his answer. Neither does Python use // as a comment indicator, nor are any of the techniques used compliant to PEP standard. A answer that should be taken with a grain of salt.